# Can not access Raspberry Pi Zero W via SSH after Hotspot setup

Tags: raspbian, ssh, hotspot

I managed to use my Raspberry Pi Zero W as hotspot. I did this headless by using SSH and my Ubuntu 17.10 laptop.

All I installed was `nginx` which serves as a web server as well as `hostapd` and `dnsmasq` to use it as a hotspot.

After rebooting the system I can no longer access the Raspberry Pi via SSH. I see that the hotspot works since my laptop detects a new wi-fi network but it does not recognize the Raspberry Pi via USB anymore. Ubuntu says "Cable unplugged" when opening the Network.

I tried a lot of tutorial the last hours but I have still not managed to access it via SSH.

How could I possibly access my Pi via SSH again? What for information would you need? I really do not want to repeat the whole process from copying the image file to the SD card to setting up all the programs I need.

I would be really glad if someone would help me to solve this problem!

Comment: What do you mean with "does not recognize the Raspberry Pi via USB anymore" ? Does you machine connect to the hotspot, do you get an IP and does the Pi respond to pings ?

Comment: @onion Before setting up the hotspot I could access the Pi via SSH using the terminal `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` and everything just worked fine. After plugging in the USB cable Ubuntu showed an `Ethernet Network` I could connect to. But now it is not possible anymore. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Samuel Consider moving/integrating any details from comments into the original question (with, perhaps, an indication that it is extra data) it could help to reduce the chances of the question being closed because it is too broad or unclear what you are asking.,,